# How to detect scrolling of UITableView?

Tags: iphone, uitableview

There is a similar question to this but answer is very general, vague.( [Detecting UITableView scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587855/detecting-uitableview-scrolling) )
Please don't dismiss. I am looking for concrete solution.

I have `UITableView` which has editable textfield and PickerView appears when another cell selected.
What I need is to hide firstResponder or PickerView when user starts scrolling this `UITableView`.

So far in question [Detecting UITableView scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587855/detecting-uitableview-scrolling) there's a sugestion that you should subclass `UITableView`. IF you subsclass `UITableView` still internal/private `UIScrollView` is not accessible. 
How do I access `UITableView`'s parent ScrollView (without breaking the law)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You don't need to subclass `UITableView` to track scrolling. Your [UITableViewDelegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) can serve as `UIScrollViewDelegate` as well. So in your **delegate** class you can implement `-scrollViewWillBeginDragging:` or whatever `UIScrollViewDelegate` method you need in your situation. (as actually suggested in the question you mention)

Comment: Thanks, I got it. jus tneed to add <UIScrollViewDelegate>  to
@interface MyTableViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>

and then implement -scrollViewWillBeginDragging:

Thanks.

Comment: How can you just get the scrolling from a specific table? Say for example I have 2 UITableViews?

Comment: @jeraldo, all UIScrollViewDelegate methods accept scroll view that calls it as parameter, so you can easily determine which UIScrollView you are dealing with

Answer (score 9):

To expand on Vladimir's answer, this is how I implemented this solution:

In .h file:

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

In .m file:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView {
    //logic here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView == myTableView){
       // Your code here.....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, and I got some ideas from the answers above to fix it, but not only the app crashes if I want to refresh while the table view is being scrolled, but also it crashes if I scroll while it's being refreshed. So the extended solution to fix the problem under all circumstances is to:

---

1.1. Disable scrolling if the user has pressed the refresh button

1.2. Enable scrolling once the refresh process is done

---

2.1. Disable the refresh button if the user is scrolling

2.2. Enable the refresh button once the user is finished scrolling

---

To implement the first part (1.1., and 1.2.):

```
-(void)startReloading:(id)sender
{
    ...
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    // and the rest of the method implementation
}

-(void)stopReloading:(id)sender
{
    self.tableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    // and the rest of the method implementation
}
```

To implement the second part (2.1., and 2.2.):

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)activeScrollView
{
    barButton.enabled = NO;
}

- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    barButton.enabled = YES;
}
```

And as it's explained in the previous answer, `UISCrollViewDelegate` needs to be set in the `.h` file:

```
@interface MyTableViewController : UITableViewController <UIScrollViewDelegate>
```

**P.S.** You can use `scrollEnabled` instead of `userInteractionEnabled`, but it all depends on what you're doing, but userInteraction is the preferred option.