# receive scroll direction, power ios

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiview

I have a view that changes if users scrolls it.
I need something to read user's scroll data (direction, force etc.) like `UITableView` does it.
if user touches screen and moves finger to the upwards view need to recieve scroll datas to call redraw method.
How can I receive scroll data?

Comment: What data do you want? Is it ony the direction of scroll?

Comment: Try this link it will help:-


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/iphone-sdk-finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-uiscrollview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes you can get both.

To get the direction of scroll you need to implement `- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` delegate.

```
int prevValue = 0;
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    int percentScrolled = abs((int)ceil((scrollView.contentOffset.y/scrollView.contentSize.height)*100));

    if(percentScrolled > prevValue)
        NSLog("Scrolling Down");
    else
        NSLog("Scrolling UP");

     prevValue = percentScrolled;
    return;
}
```

Now to get the force or power of scrolling. you actually need to set something called `decelerateRate` for your scrollView (or tableView). Refer [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html).

Comment: It will work if I have a custom view that needs to be redrawed depending on where the users moves finger after he touches screen?

Comment: I haven't got a UIScrollView object. I have UIView objects that rotate if user presses and moves finger on the screen (scrolling). So I need something to get scroll data from.