# Detect direction of UIScrollView scroll in scrollViewWillBeginDragging

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I did google enough, & I did check posts like these ( [Finding the direction of scrolling in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/iphone-sdk-finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-uiscrollview) ) in stackoverflow before posting this. I have a dynamic number of photos in an iPhone App, that am displaying through `UIScrollView`. At any point in time, I have only 3 photos being displayed in the scroll-view. When I have, say 4 photos, in total:
1st photo : displayed at offset 0.0
2nd photo : displayed at offset 320.0
3rd photo : displayed at offset 640.0

Now, when the user scrolls to the 4th photo, the scroll-view resets to 0.0 offset. If the user tries to scroll 'beyond' the 4th photo, scrolling should stop in the right-direction only (so that user doesn't scroll 'beyond'). But currently, the user 'is able' to scroll beyond the last photo ; however, I detect this programmatically & reset the offset. But it doesn't look neat, as the user sees the black background momentarily. I want to detect that the user has started scrolling 'right' (remember, scrolling 'left' i.e. to the 'previous' photo is okay) in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging`, so that I can stop any further scrolling to the right.

What I tried:

1. Trying using `self.scrollView.panGestureRecognizer`'s
   `translationInView` isn't working, because there is no
   `panGestureRecognizer` instance returned in the first place (!),
   though the UIScrollView API claims so.
2. Detecting this in `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating` is possible, though
   it'll not serve my purpose.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you, Kris. This is what worked for me, finally:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // Detect the scroll direction
    if (lastContentOffset < (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on lastContentOffset

Comment: @Daniel you need to save the "last content offset", which is the previous contentOffset from the last time this method was called. I don't know why Jean forgot it. Just add lastContentOffset as static variable at the top, then set it at the end of the method.

Answer (score 28):

I had no issues determining direction in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` when checking the scroll view's `panGestureRecognizer`:

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 
    CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

    if(translation.y > 0)
    {
        // react to dragging down
    } else
    {
        // react to dragging up
    }
}
```

I found it very useful in canceling out of a scroll at the very first drag move when the user is dragging in a forbidden direction.

Comment: translation appears to be always zero (in iOS7.1 at least)

Comment: translation will sometimes be zero, so this only 'kindof' works (iOS 8.3)

Comment: use `scrollViewDidScroll` instead

Comment: If `translation > 0` - UP!

Comment: Note, the translation can return zero if the gesture is too subtle. Use CGPoint velocity = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer velocityInView:scrollView.superview]; instead. Credit to User Robert in a comment to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9637203/check-direction-of-scroll-in-uiscrollview

Answer (score 15):

**Swift 3 Solution**

1- Add UIScrollViewDelegate

2- Add this code

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let actualPosition = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView.superview)
    if (actualPosition.y > 0){
        // Dragging down
    }else{
        // Dragging up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 12):

For swift 2.0+ & ios 8.0+

```
func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let actualPosition = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(scrollView.superview)
    if (actualPosition.y > 0){
        // Dragging down 
    }else{
        // Dragging up
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This is what I used and it works nicely at least on iOS 6.0:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView*)scrollView
{
   CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView];

   // Detect direction by accessing x or y of translation
}
```

Saves you the instance variable for `lastContentOffset` ...

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at `scrollViewWillEndDragging:withVelocity:targetContentOffset:`.
You can use that method do do any checking and see if it is going where it should not and then in the method you can set a new `targetContentOffset`.

Per [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate_protocol/reference/uiscrollviewdelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewWillEndDragging%3awithVelocity%3atargetContentOffset%3a):

> This method is not called when the value of the scroll view’s pagingEnabled property is YES. Your application can change the value of the targetContentOffset parameter to adjust where the scrollview finishes its scrolling animation.

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be issues with detecting scroll direction based on the translation of the scrollView's pan recognizer in iOS 7+. This seems to be working pretty seamlessly for my purposes

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if !scrollDirectionDetermined {
        let translation = scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translationInView(self.view)
        if translation.y > 0 {
            println("UP")
            scrollDirectionDetermined = true
        }
        else if translation.y < 0 {
            println("DOWN")
            scrollDirectionDetermined = true
        }
    }
}

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollDirectionDetermined = false
}

func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    scrollDirectionDetermined = false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView` doesn't report anything useful in `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` in iOS 7.

This does:

In the `@interface`

```
BOOL scrollDirectionDetermined;
```

and:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (!scrollDirectionDetermined) {
        if ([scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview].x > 0) {
            //scrolling rightwards
        } else {
             //scrolling leftwards
       }
    scrollDirectionDetermined = YES;
    }
}
```

and:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    scrollDirectionDetermined = NO;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Building off of @Oscar's answer, you can do things like

`scrollView.bounces = actualPosition.y < 0` if you want the scrollView to bounce when you scroll to the bottom but not when you scroll to the top