# How to make UICollectionheader transparent while scrolling up?

Tags: objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

Please help me to make the UICollectionview header transparent while we scroll the collection view up. I have used UICollectionReusableView and set it background as clear color, but no use. WHILE MOVING UP THE HEADER ( SHOWN IN BLACK COLOR) SHOULD BECOME TRANSPARENT.... THAT IS THE ORANGE BACKGROUND SHOULD BE SLIGHTLY VISIBLE....

[image]

Comment: Could you, please, be more specific? In what moment do you set background of UICollectionReusableView? How do you access it?
The best would be, if you can post some code

Comment: And what do you mean, "UICollectionview header". It's not quite clear, 'cause UICollectionView doesn't have `header` property (like UITableView has)

Answer (score 0):

Not enough info, but I'll try to answer

First, you should keep pointer to your header view constantly

```
@property UICollectionReusableView *collectionHeaderView;
```

Create it once in `viewDidLoad` and than use it as a header view (whatever that means) in your collection view.

Next, to change collor on dragging up you'll need delegate method.
UICollectionViewDelegate conforms to UIScrollViewDelegate, so you can use its method

```
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{ 
     CGPoint translation = [scrollView.panGestureRecognizer translationInView:scrollView.superview];

     if(translation.y > 0)
     {
        //dragging down
        collectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = <#Whatever you need#>;
     } else
     {
         // dragging up
         collectionHeaderView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
     }
 }
```

*Special thanks to @mvielbut for [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412370/5016443)*

**Update**

According to comments to mvielbut's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19412370/5016443), this method is not always reliable, so you can use [another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14055899/5016443) approach (you'll need to check `offset.y` instead).

Comment: @ SERGII PLEASE SEE THE PHOTO THAT I POSTED.. :)

Comment: Like I said, not enough info. Your photo doesn't provide any new info

Comment: WHAT OTHER INFO YOU WANT ? PLEASE TELL :)

Comment: Read my comments. And check my answer. I believe, it should help. P. S. I can see clearly, so, please, turn caps lock off

Comment: sorry my caps lock just got stuck :)