# scroll direction in UIScrollView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

how to know when the scrollview is scrolled vertically or horizontally? 
i wanted to know the direction of UIScrollview.?

please do help,

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/iphone-sdk-finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-uiscrollview

Answer (score 1):

You should have look into the [contentOffset](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset) property of the scroll view.

Comment: You can find sample code when you follow the link in the comment of Binyamin Sharet below your question.