# UIScrollView direction of scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I would like to copy the effect seen in Pinterest app, where they hide top and bottom bars depending on the direction of scrolling. My question is: what is the correct way to determine which way the UIScrollView is scrolling?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This is the solution:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    pointNow = scrollView.contentOffset;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<pointNow.y) {
        DLog(@"down");
    } else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y>pointNow.y) {
        DLog(@"up");
    }
}
```

Comment: To avoid an issue when your scrolling holding the click pressed, add the "pointNow = scrollView.contentOffset;" after if condition.

Comment: I would use if (scrollView.contentOffset.y<=pointNow.y)  just to keep it up when it first gets to the view controller :)

Answer (score 1):

Use the methods from `UIScrolViewDelegate's` protocol. You can find the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate.html).