# uiscrollview direction not showing up after first scroll

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview

im trying to find out user scroll direction or even if possible user gesture swipt

on uiscrollview.

at first i tried this code :

```
 UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipe = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeScreen:)];
swipe.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
[self.uiscroll addGestureRecognizer:swipe];

- (void)didSwipeScreen:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)gesture
{
    switch (gesture.direction) {
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp:
            NSLog(@"UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp");
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown:
            NSLog(@"UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown");
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft:
             NSLog(@"UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft");
            break;
        case UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight:
            NSLog(@"UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight");
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

but nothing happend when i swipes.

so im trying the built in method for scroll drag like this :

```
 @property (nonatomic, assign) CGPoint lastContentOffset;
- (void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"first _lastContentOffset.x : %f",_lastContentOffset.x);

    _lastContentOffset.x = scrollView.contentOffset.x;
    _lastContentOffset.y = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

}
- (void)scrollViewDidEndDecelerating:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    NSLog(@"_lastContentOffset.x : %f",_lastContentOffset.x);
    NSLog(@"(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x: %d",(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x);
    if (_lastContentOffset.x < (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        NSLog(@"right");

    }
    else if (_lastContentOffset.x > (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x) {
        NSLog(@"left");

    }else if (_lastContentOffset.y<(int)scrollView.contentOffset.y){
        NSLog(@"up");

    }else if (_lastContentOffset.y>(int)scrollView.contentOffset.y){
        NSLog(@"down");


    }
}
```

the problem with second method is , it stops working after first scroll.

the first scroll works well but the second stucks.

this the log output for first and second right scrolling:

```
2015-02-05 15:57:09.675 app[4792:554076] first _lastContentOffset.x : 0.000000
2015-02-05 15:57:09.798 app[4792:554076] _lastContentOffset.x : 0.000000
2015-02-05 15:57:09.800 app[4792:554076] (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x: 8
2015-02-05 15:57:09.801 app[4792:554076] right
2015-02-05 15:57:10.422 app[4792:554076] first _lastContentOffset.x : 0.000000
2015-02-05 15:57:10.548 app[4792:554076] _lastContentOffset.x : 8.000000
2015-02-05 15:57:10.549 app[4792:554076] (int)scrollView.contentOffset.x: 8
2015-02-05 15:57:15.146 app[4792:554076] first _lastContentOffset.x : 8.000000
2015-02-05 15:57:15.365 app[4792:554076] _lastContentOffset.x : 8.000000
```

Comment: Where are you declaring the gesture recognizer?

Comment: Best answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11262583/uiscrollview-direction-of-scrolling?rq=1

Comment: @AshrafTawfeeq im declaring it on viewdidload

Comment: @Dover8 What's the Difference ? im using same method.

Comment: You are using scrollViewDidEndDecelerating which will only be called after deceleration. If the user drags the scrollview into position before releasing this method won't be called.

However, with the sample output you have above, in the second case: _lastContentOffset.x : 8.000000
(int)scrollView.contentOffset.x: 8
Therefore they are equal and you don't have an if/else case for that in your code.

Using scrollViewDidScroll you will get output everytime there is a scroll.

Comment: @Dover8 thanks for comment. that was the problem. the answer within if/else condition.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is in

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft | UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
```

Sadly, you have to create 2 gestures to get it work properly.

And the scroll view gets confused between the gesture and the scroll it has.

Comment: even if i remove one them , still nothing happen.

Comment: I found out that the problem is in the UIScrollView. The scroll view get confused between the gesture and the scroll it has.