# Add gesture recognizer to scrollview perpendicular to scrolling

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer

I have a scrollview through which the user can swipe left and right to navigate and tap on the elements in it, but I also want to add the ability to swipe up or down on the scrollview (perpendicular to the scrolling direction) to perform some other actions. However, when I tried to add the gesture recognizers to it, it didn't seem to make a difference. I then tried layering another view on top of it and adding the gesture recognizers to that, the gesture recognizers worked, but I couldn't figure out how to pass the rest of the touches down through it. What's the best approach here?

Comment: Maybe post some code?

Answer (score 0):

Set the delegate for scrollview you have added,

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) NSInteger lastContentOffset
//
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender 
{
   if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y)
        // down direction
   else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) 
        // up direction
   self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;

   // do whatever you need to with scrollDirection here.    
}
```

You can get help from this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/ios-finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview) also.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain properly - I don't actually want the scrollview to allow scrolling up or down - I just want it to slide left and right. If the user swipes up or down on it, I want to perform other actions.