# How to get UIWebView page number

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I used following code to paginate the `UIWebView`.

```
self.webView.paginationMode = UIWebPaginationModeLeftToRight;
self.webView.paginationBreakingMode = UIWebPaginationBreakingModePage;
self.webView.scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;
```

Now I want to know the total number of pages it created. The IOS7 document says `UIWebView` has a property called `pageCount`. I tried it, but it always returns 1.

How can I get the number of pages it created after pagination?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want only the number of pages you can use CoreGraphics

```
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:@"your path"]);
int pageCount = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
```

If you want to count pages for HTML content you need to set delegate

```
self.webView.delegate = self;
```

and to implement UIWebViewDelegate method

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
{
    NSUInteger count1 = webView.pageCount; // for iOS7 only!

    NSUInteger count2 = webView.scrollView.contentSize.width / webView.scrollView.frame.size.width; // for horizontal paging

    NSUInteger count3 = webView.scrollView.contentSize.height / webView.scrollView.frame.size.height; // for vertical paging
}
```

Note that you can get pageCount only after full rendering of the requested HTML page.

Comment: I am using UIWebView to display HTML instead of PDF. Is there a way to show the total paginated page numbers?

Comment: Thanks. This works. I also notice I can put pageCount inside `viewDidAppear` and it also works.

Comment: Exactly. Rendering is done by the time of viewDidAppear. But if you want to load pages by some user request you need delegates.

Comment: Note that you can set the pageLength property to split in multiple columns

Comment: @malex: Will this work for document as well like word, excel which i am displaying in UIWebView. I am looking for Pagecount and horizontal/Vertical scrolling of these documents.

Comment: @ArunGupta, it should work for any web content. Anyway It's better to try.

Comment: @Malex: I tried for different documents and pagecount (webView.scrollView.contentSize.height / webView.scrollView.frame.size.height) property seems to be working in case of vertical scrolling.  It is possible to get the current page or page number when scrolling.

Answer (score 1):

UIWebView is a subclass of UIScrollView. You can detect UIWebView page change event for scroll view delegate method:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

This delegate will be called each time the webView scrolls. Maintain your page number yourself. You can use scrollView.contentOffset.x and scrollView.contentOffset.y to determine the scrolling direction.

You can find more help [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview).

**EDIT**
We can find page number of scrollview from contentoffset. Try something similar for webView.
    int page = scrollView.contentOffset.x / scrollView.frame.size.width;

Comment: I need to know the total number of pages before I scroll the page. I need to pass this value to the PageControl display the dots. In fact, I used similar function to get page `self.pageControl.numberOfPages = self.webView.scrollView.contentSize.width / pageWidth;`, but the `scrollView.contentSize.width` only shows one page width. I would expect it shows the width of all pages.

Comment: Did you tried scrollView.contentOffset.x inted of contentSize.width??