# ios swift - blur background image behind scrollview

Tags: ios, scrollview

I'm trying to achieve an effect similar to the one shown in the gif below.

I put an image in the background and a scroll view over it.

However, it confuses me as to how to blur the background image when i begin scrolling.

please advise.

[image]

Comment: Try to change the background colour of the scrollview with black colour and alpha component in scrollViewDidScroll method

Comment: Have you tried `visual Effect view with blur` in Storyboard?

Comment: its name parallex scrolling, google it once you get answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this, add a blur subview to imageView when scroll begin:

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    var visualEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: .Light))

    visualEffectView.frame = yourIimageView.bounds

    yourImageView.addSubview(visualEffectView)

}
```

You may also want to track the direction of scroll, so when you scroll up, the blur show up, when scroll down, the blur disappear. You can have a look at this post to see how to detect it.

[ios UICollectionView detect scroll direction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24480436/ios-uicollectionview-detect-scroll-direction)