# Material floating action button should invisible when user scroll down and visible when scrolls up

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiscrollview

I have material Floating action button (FAB) at right bottom of screen.
Also, I have CollectionView inside View. I want below actions to be done.

1. When user scrolls down - FAB should invisible.
2. When user scrolls up  -  FAB should visible.

I've searched everywhere in google.None of questions satisfied my requirements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

don't forget to set collectionView.delegate = self.

```
extension ViewController: UIScrollViewDelegate{
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if scrollView == collectoinView{
            button.isHidden = scrollView.contentOffset.y > 50
        }
    }
}
```

**50** is the position of **Y** from which the button will hide. You can adjust to any number according to your requirement.

---

Another Way of doing that

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {

    let targetPoint = targetContentOffset as? CGPoint
    let currentPoint = scrollView.contentOffset

    if (targetPoint?.y ?? 0.0) > currentPoint.y {
        print("up")

    } else {
        print("down")
     }
}
```

with the second approach, there is no need to provide static value. the second approach has been converted to Swift from objective-c [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36644808/2299040)

Comment: @Eswar glad it helped. don't forget to upvote and accept the answer. thanks

Comment: button hiding is working perfect. but - button becomes visible only when first cell displayed. I want it to be displayed if user scrolls up regardless of cell count.

Comment: You can change the value *50* according to your requirement

Comment: I don't want to give any static value. I just need to know whether user has scrolled up or down. if UP - button should visible,  if DOWN - button should hide. How can i achieve this?

Comment: @Eswar another way added.

Comment: "**Cast from 'UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>' to unrelated type 'CGPoint' always fails**"  - This is the **WARNING** by Xcode at the line "**let targetPoint = targetContentOffset as? CGPoint**"

Comment: No - Second way is not working as expected. Though it reached last cell, button is still visible. When i touch and drag the view - then the  button is hiding.

Comment: I copied and basically translated(the second way) to swift.  I'll look into it and get back to you

Comment: Sure. Will wait for that. Meantime -  i will try to achieve desired result with first approach.

Comment: Can we take help of UISwipeGestureRecognizer with first approach to meet the requirement?

Answer (score 0):

You can use scrollViewDidScroll for this.

```
     func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView!) {
    if (self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        // show your button
    }
    else if (self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) { 
       // hide your button
    }

    // update the new position acquired
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Comment: When i tried your code - This error is raised  "**Value of type 'ViewController' has no member 'lastContentOffset'**".

Comment: oh sorry. i forgot to add this. lastContentOffset is a simple CGFloat variable. You should add it somewhere in your code. (like this var lastContentOffset : CGFloat = 0)

Answer (score 0):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQGGO.png

1. Call the Method ---> func scrollViewWillEndDragging
2. Call the method for the Animation --> func setView

Comment: please write your code here in question instead of uploading pic so that other people can copy paste and test your code and then it's easy to evaluate

Comment: Yeah Next time I will Paste Code Sorry for now

Answer (score 0):

here is the above code.

```
 func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {
     moveDownButton.isHidden = false
    
    if targetContentOffset.pointee.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        //Going up
        setView(view: self.moveDownButton, hidden: false)
    } else {
        //Going Down
        setView(view: self.moveDownButton, hidden: true)
    }
}

func setView(view: UIView, hidden: Bool) {
    view.isHidden = hidden
}
```