# How to know that when the user swipe up / down?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I have `UICollectionView` in my `ViewController` (Please check below attached image for view hierarchy). How can we detect when the user swipes up or down?

It doesn't matter if we add gesture recognizer to `UIView` or `UICollectionView`. I just want to know the swipe gesture.

[image: View Hierarchy]

I've tried adding gesture recognizer to `UIView` and `UICollectionView` by using codes in stack overflow. But none of them satisfied my requirement.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is too broad. What have you tried so far? What is the specific roadblocks you are running into? What error are you getting? What is not working?

Comment: You don't need any gesture reco. Collection view is inherits UIScrollview  so you can  set delegate of collectionview to self and implement UIScrollViewDelegate methods

Comment: @Andreas  -   i have tried adding UISwipeGestureRecognizer() to UIView and UICollectionView. No error has been raised. but didn't get desired result.                    please refer this link for my issue related to this question - "** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787905/material-floating-action-button-should-invisible-when-user-scroll-down-and-visib/56788054?noredirect=1#comment100131775_56788054 **"

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya - even i did that what you have suggested. Please refer this link for exact issue related to my question here  - "** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56787905/material-floating-action-button-should-invisible-when-user-scroll-down-and-visib/56788054?noredirect=1#comment100131775_56788054 **"

Comment: There are many questions that talks about how to detect the direction in which the user has scrolled a scroll view, such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14042203/detect-direction-of-uiscrollview-scroll-in-scrollviewwillbegindragging/16964554) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview/26192103). They should help/

Answer (score 1):

Since `collectionView` is a basically a `scrollView`, use `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` method to identify the scrolling direction of the `collectionView`.

```
private var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0.0
```

In the above code, `lastContentOffset` keep track of the previous `contentOffset` of the `collectionView` while scrolling.

```
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.lastContentOffset) {
        //Scrolling up
    }
    else if (scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastContentOffset) {
        //Scrolling down
    }
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}
```

Don't forget to conform to `UICollectionViewDelegate` protocol.

Also, there is no need for adding any separate `gestureRecognizer`. `UICollectionView` being a `UIScrollView` will handle it on its own.