# UICollectionView Swipe

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I want to detect when a user swipes left or right in a collectionView in which one cell occupies the entire screen width. Is it possible to do without adding gesture recognizer. I have tried adding gesture recogniser, but it only works when we set scrollEnabled property of collectionView to NO.

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRight = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeRight:)];
swipeRight.delegate = self;
swipeRight.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[swipeRight setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeLeft = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(didSwipeLeft:)];
swipeLeft.delegate = self;
swipeLeft.numberOfTouchesRequired = 1;
[swipeLeft setDirection:UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionLeft];

[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:swipeLeft];
[self.collectionView addGestureRecognizer:swipeRight];
```

Comment: why you want to use swipe gesture?

Comment: I want to do some processing on detecting whether it is left or right swipe

Comment: Does the collection view scroll vertical or horizontal?  Is the real question just that you want to detect left/right swipes on a collection view or that you really don't want a gesture recognizer to do it?

Comment: horizontal, i don't want a gesture recogniser as i have this collection view as a cell inside another collection view.

Comment: UICollectionView is one type of scrollview so you can override scrollViewDidScroll to check the direction of scrolling. Check this answer - [http://stackoverflow.com/a/4073028/900024]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you have disabled userInteraction. Did you check it? And define gestures as property to the class.

```
self.collectionView.setUserInteractionEnabled=true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to override `scrollViewWillEndDragging:scrollView withVelocity:velocity targetContentOffset:targetContentOffset`, since the collection view inherits from a scroll view. This  way you should be able to evaluate the velocity parameter to determine the direction. Therefore you'll want to implement the `UIScrollViewDelegate` protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I add swipe gesture to collectionView.
And it work fine.

So like Stephen Johnson said.
I guess your cell have a scrollView.
So It block gestures.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I fully understand the context of your problem.  I see that you have a collection view within a collection view.  I am going to assume that the outer collection view scrolls vertical and the inner one scrolls horizontal.  You will want to set up a fail dependency between the gesture recognizers for both collections.

```
//Data source for your outer collection view
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
                  cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   ...
   UICollectionView* innerCollectionView = ...;

   [collectionView. panGestureRecognizer requireGestureRecognizerToFail:innerCollectionView. panGestureRecognizer];

   ...
}
```

If there is more going on than this with nested collection views can you give some more details?