# auto hiding and showing UINavigationBar like Instagram iOS app

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uinavigationcontroller, instagram

I have this snippet of code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    UINavigationBar *navbar =self.navigationController.navigationBar;
    UIView *tableView = self.view;
    CGRect navBarFrame = self.navigationController.navigationBar.frame;

    CGRect tableFrame = self.view.frame;

    //changing the origin.y based on the current scroll view.
    //Adding +20 for the Status Bar since the offset is tied into that.

    navBarFrame.origin.y = MIN(0, MAX(-44, (scrollView.contentOffset.y * -1)))  +20 ;
    tableFrame.origin.y = navBarFrame.origin.y + navBarFrame.size.height;

    navbar.frame = navBarFrame;
    tableView.frame = tableFrame;

}
```

this gives the desired effect of hiding my navigation bar, but the navigation will only re-appear if you scroll to the top of the scrollview (y offset = 0). how can I recreate Instagram's behaviour where the navbar reappears whenever you scroll up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've scrapped the manual frame code for this more intuitive code:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {

    if (lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        if (downwards) {
            downwards = NO;
            scrollDistance = 0;
        } else {
            scrollDistance++;
        }
    }
    else if (lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y) {
        if (!downwards) {
            downwards = YES;
            scrollDistance = 0;
        } else {
            scrollDistance++;
        }
    }
    lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y;
    CGFloat threshold = 10;
    if (downwards && !self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden && scrollDistance > threshold) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    } else if (!downwards && self.navigationController.navigationBarHidden && scrollDistance > threshold) {
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
    }

}
```

This also adds a 10px threshold so that it only reacts to a meaningful scroll up or down

Comment: This looks much better than what you had posted in the question, good work!

Answer (score 1):

Use this link to detect scroll direction: [Detect Scroll Direction](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073028/3543861)

I don't really understand what you are doing with your code that you posted.  Are you creating a new navigation bar each time or hiding and showing the same one?

Anyways, once you detect scroll direction, just show the navigation bar when `ScrollDirection = ScrollDirectionUp`.

Something like:

```
if (ScrollDirection == ScrollDirectionUp) {
    self.navigationController.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
}
```

Comment: you were right, I ended up messing up my views (I'm using autolayout so the manual frame code didn't work well) - I've added my solution