# what is the default method of scroll view while horizontal scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, scrollview

I have three view added to a scroll view, also i have added horizontal swipe in scroll view but I need to call a web service for each swipe, can any one help which scroll view method is used for calling the web service for horizontal swiping.

Answer (score 1):

The `scrollView` delegate method for scrolling is `scrollViewDidScroll(_:)` - [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScrollViewDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIScrollViewDelegate/scrollViewDidScroll:)

For finding the direction of scroll (in case you have multiple) you can check out this answer:

[Finding the direction of scrolling in a UIScrollView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)