# iOS make UIScrollView paging enabled only for one direction

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiscrollview

As the question title says, is it possible to enable paging in `UIScrollView` only for one direction?

I have a `UIScrollView` that scrolls in both x and y directions, but I want only one direction to be paginated, is this possible?

The only solution that came in my mind is to have another `UIScrollView` inside the first, is this the only solution?

Comment: This sounds like a very complicated design. Have you considered other approaches? such as breaking your UI up into tableViewCells? and having only one (or more) of those horizontally scroll?

Comment: I can't use TableViews, the design is too complex. I have to use scrollviews

Answer (score 1):

You should implement `scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating delegate method of`UIScrollview`.

You should store current `content offset` somewhere.

then compare `y` of your scrollview's current `content offset` and last stored  with `content offset`. If current `y` is greater then scroll direction is `up side` and if last stored `y` is greater then direction is `down side`. Now if you want `paging` effect on `up direction` only then when you detect `up direction` set new `content offset` to your `scrollview`. for example if current `y` offset is `0` then set it to `y+screenheight`.

You can refer [this so post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview) for some guidance to manage what i have said!

Answer (score 1):

This is how I solved it:

First, set to set your `scrollView`'s delegate, which could look like:

```
scrollView.delegate = self
```

And then

```
var lastOffsetY: CGFloat = 0
var lastOffsetX: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.contentOffset.y != lastOffsetY {
        lastOffsetY = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
    } else {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    }
    if scrollView.contentOffset.x != lastOffsetX {
        lastOffsetX = scrollView.contentOffset.x
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = true
    } else {
        scrollView.isPagingEnabled = false
    }
}
```

This will make only it pageable in horizontal direction. For vertical direction just flip the true/false values.