# Detect pan Gesture Swipe Down in TableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, keyboard, messaging

I have table view controller and which will show all the chatting messages. Inside that tableview controller I have stickers view where user can send stickers. I want to detect swipe down function in tableview and if user create swipe downs, I want to close stickers view if sticker view is already opened. Tableview has scrollview event also that's why I cannot detect swipe down event. My sticker view is same as fb messenger sticker view.

[image: Please see the attached screenshot for sticker view]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a gesture, you should use the UIScrollviewDelegate methods to determine if the tableview has scrolled down, then trigger the desired behavior you want.

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4073028/1219956) on how to implement it

Comment: also calculate the speed in the direction as swipe down should be a quick gesture

Answer (score 0):

- for hiding inputview you can use tableview ' dismiss on dram ' attribute from storyboard,

[image: storyboard image]

Comment: thanks but its not input view. it is just a UIView. @Yogesh Makwana