# iOS tableview how can I check if it is scrolling up or down

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3

I am learning how to work with TableViews and I am wondering how can I figure out if the tableView is scrolling up or down ? I been trying various things such as this but it hasn't worked granted that below is for a scrollview and I have a TableView . Any suggestions would be great as I am new at this ...

```
  func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if scrollView.panGestureRecognizer.translation(in: scrollView).y < 0 {
        print("down")
    } else {
        print("up")
    }
}
```

This is what I have in my tableView code

```
func tableView(_ tableView:UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section:Int) -> Int {
        return Locations.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == self.Posts.count - 4 {

            reloadTable(latmin: self.latmin,latmax: self.latmax,lonmin: self.lonmin,lonmax: self.lonmax,my_id: myID)
            print("Load More")
        }

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "HomePageTVC", for: indexPath) as! NewCell


   cell.post.text = Posts[indexPath.row]
   cell.fullname.setTitle(FullName[indexPath.row],for: UIControlState.normal)

        return cell
    }
```

Comment: A `UITableView` is a `UIScrollView`. All of the `UIScrollViewDelegate` methods work with a table view.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Finding the direction of scrolling in a UIScrollView?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2543670/finding-the-direction-of-scrolling-in-a-uiscrollview)

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Like @maddy said in the comment of your question, you can check if your `UITableView` is scrolling by using the `UIScrollViewDelegate` and further more you could check which direction it scrolls to by using both `scrollViewDidScroll` and `scrollViewWillBeginDragging` functions

```
// we set a variable to hold the contentOffSet before scroll view scrolls
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

// this delegate is called when the scrollView (i.e your UITableView) will start scrolling
func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}

// while scrolling this delegate is being called so you may now check which direction your scrollView is being scrolled to
func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    if self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // did move up
    } else if self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // did move down
    } else {
        // didn't move
    }
}
```

**Furthermore**: You don't need to subclass your `UIViewController` with `UIScrollViewDelegate` if you've already subclassed your `UIViewController` with  `UITableViewDelegate` because `UITableViewDelegate` is already a subclass of `UIScrollViewDelegate`

Comment: @Rome Torres please accept as the correct answer if it helped Thanks.

Comment: How can I make this less sensitive for scrolling up? For instance, if I wanted to only cause an action if the tableview is scrolled upwards fast.

Answer (score 33):

You can implement `scrollViewWillEndDragging` method:

```
func scrollViewWillEndDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView, withVelocity velocity: CGPoint, targetContentOffset: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGPoint>) {


    if targetContentOffset.pointee.y < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        // it's going up
    } else {
        // it's going down
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that helped

Comment: This should be the answer!!

Comment: The cleanest solution

Comment: Definitely this is the answer!

Comment: Unfortunately, this variant doesn't work until you lift your finger

Answer (score 0):

first we should make two property for last Offset and Current Offset

```
 var lastOffset = CGFloat()
 var currentOffset = CGFloat()
```

then in the Scrollview VC call the scrollViewWillBeginDragging for get current offset

```
 override func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        self.lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y

    }
```

and scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating for get last offset

```
    override func scrollViewWillBeginDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        self.lastOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        viewStatus(scrollView: scrollView)

    }
```

then with this two variable you can know your scrollview W
here it goes‍‍‍‍

```
‍‍‍let isScrollUp = scrollView.contentOffset.y > self.lastOffset
let isScrollDown  = scrollView.contentOffset.y < self.lastOffset
```