# How to use pagination in table view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift4

Basically i have a table view and get 5 item in every time when i call the api. So how to use/ reload more data white scrolling table view.
array.count-1 not for me at cell for row indexpath because when device size bigger all data shown at a time and api not call

Comment: You should trigged your call in `tableViewWillDisplayCell`. Every time the indexPath is reaching the last of your local count, fetch the API

Answer (score 0):

You should be sending the page number in the API request.

**First:** declare the variable `currentPage` with initial value 0 and a boolean to check if any list is being loaded with initial value false, it's to prevent the scroll view from getting more lists/items in one scroll to the bottom of the tableView.

```
var currentPage = 0
var isLoadingList = false
```

**Second:** This is the function that fetches the data:

```
func getFromServer(_ pageNumber: Int){
     self.isloadingList = false
     self.table.reloadData()
}
```

**Third:** Implement the function that increments the page number and calls the API function on the current page.

```
func loadMoreItems(){
     currentPage += 1
     getFromServer(currentPage)
}
```

**Fourth:** When the scrollView scrolls you should get the other items/lists from the API.

```
    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        if (((scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.frame.size.height) > scrollView.contentSize.height ) && !isLoadingList){
            self.isLoadingList = true
            self.loadMoreItems()
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works fine but how if i scroll above, data not load while scrolling above

Comment: Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35213858/5025731)

Answer (score 0):

You should implement the [`UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching` protocol](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableviewdatasourceprefetching). This protocol will help you to fill seamlessly a table by new data

Comment: can you please send me demo how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Declare

current page = 1

Then add this method in viewController

```
private func isLastCell(indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    print(indexPath)
    if array.count > 0 {
        return ((indexPath.section == sectionCount-1) && (indexPath.row == (array.count-1)))
    } else {
        return false
    }
```

}

After that in tableViewWillDisplayCell method add this function

```
if array.count > 0, self.isLastCell(indexPath: indexPath) {
            self.currentPage += 1
            // call api here
  }
```

It works for me